# jQuery validation custom wrapper

Tags: jquery, css, validation, bulletedlist

is it possible to set custom li wrapper for jQuery form validation?
Maybe with css?

It's a  beginning of my jQuery validation code:

```
$("#sign-in-form").validate({
        onkeyup: function(element){$(element).valid()},
        onfocusout: false,
        errorLabelContainer: "#loginError",
        wrapper: "li",
        ...
```

I have a circle in my output. I'd like to have no bullet here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS.

```
li { list-style-type: none; }
```

PS: this is a general style, you should use a class for the `li` element.